# How to retrieve the private keys from keycloack realms keys?

Tags: private-key, keycloak-rest-api

I am trying to get private keys from keycloack realms keys .
I am able to get public keys using
Open-id/certs api.please let me know if able to get private keys of realms in keycloack.

Answer (score 10):

I use the private key, to write tests to tamper the JWT payload to verify an application. I got all securiy pitfalls

Getting private key with MySQL is easy:

```
use <kc_db_schema>;
SELECT VALUE FROM COMPONENT_CONFIG CC INNER JOIN COMPONENT C INNER JOIN REALM R ON(CC.COMPONENT_ID = C.ID AND R.ID = C.REALM_ID)
WHERE R.NAME='your-realm-name' AND C.NAME = 'rsa-generated' AND CC.name = 'privateKey';
```

Using this privateKey value I'm able to sign my payload.
In Python PyJWT it is **VERY** important to add the '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----' / '-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----' with linefeeds to the key:

```
private_key = b"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n<my privateKey from SQL query>\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
jwt_encoded = jwt.encode({my payload}, private_key, algorithm="RS256")
```

Comment: The query is awesome, but there is a small typo as you are not including the `ON` condition in the second join.

The correct query would be:

```SELECT value 
FROM component_config cc 
INNER JOIN component c 
  ON cc.component_id=c.id 
INNER JOIN realm r 
  ON realm_id=r.id 
WHERE 
  r.name='<my-realm>' AND 
  c.name = 'rsa-generated' AND 
  cc.name='privateKey'
;

```

Comment: My query works as well, because my ON condition is a logical link in brackets: `ON(CC.COMPONENT_ID = C.ID AND R.ID = C.REALM_ID)`

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get private keys from keycloack database and table name is component_config.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

at recent versions of Keycloak, there is DefaultKeyManager which can be used to retrieve keys from realms.

```
KeyManager keyManager = new DefaultKeyManager(keycloakSession);
Key key = keyManager.getActiveKey(keycloakSession.getContext().getRealm(), KeyUse.SIG, "RS256").getPrivateKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using the Keycloak's internal database is great, but I just thought of a new one. By exporting your realm (more information [here](https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport)), you can easily inspect the JSON file and find the precise information you need.

This is, with your Keycloak server stopped, in the main folder execute:

```
bin\kc.[sh|bat] export --file "name-of-your-realm.json" --realm <your-realm>
```

where `"name-of-your-realm.json"` should be replaced with the path of the future exportation file and `<your-realm>` with the name of the realm.

Finally, as I have previously said, open the JSON file and Ctrl + F `privateKey`, `rsa-generated`, or whatever information you need.

[image: Keycloak private key in realm export file]

Answer (score -2):

Well, you are not allowed to. **That is why they are called private keys**, you can't expect a private key through API.

Private keys are private to the holder, you can learn more about them [here](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/symmetric-vs-asymmetric-cryptography).

Comment: Is there any table in keycloack stores the private key and public keys?

Comment: You can learn more about keys in keycloak here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/server_admin/topics/realms/keys.adoc

You can mark my original answer as accepted answer for the people in the future who visit and get help by your question.